# Worldpay create CC Authorization Request

Tags: worldpay

I am trying to create an authorization request with front-end encrypted data.
My First encrypted data is :

> eyJhbGciOiJSU0ExXzUiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwia2lkIjoiMSIsImNvbS53b3JsZHBheS5hcGlWZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4wIiwiY29tLndvcmxkcGF5LmxpYlZlcnNpb24iOiIxLjAuMSIsImNvbS53b3JsZHBheS5jaGFubmVsIjoiamF2YXNjcmlwdCJ9.NdjUwAHMuc3f_YIfti3VHcDLUbvUD58z76WVmS3_PqjktboxS12lwocooA5Py30aADsf4f3slAsxvVBMM_GC7uAv55-6o87RMkoVZWfhmibMoQfkmgijUfQ9R4nVi5kBXWzzFurQDi9dqLb-dRrSQBQb7IkAboA_UXf5X3bcr71yULudDULHOS_0cBSu9Csw2m1dZEtu6X_Ofayvw9ujTX7DHgNcAIdQoVQlYkWUKEv45pfeLvsv_yL4jV4TMlBOGLt-Hw0VXUSIrMCQ_239qAHIUsPU5mWoXmBbGtOWXZz7H-3RHg8xoU0DqPqwTELtQSEV_Zv-I0uQOx3T17cK5Q.8oKxgccRVID8cabx.mPQtAneIy6Y9fqYtMXHqQ0KZCXJMPV9D0aoijB7YO-nxjroUzW1xzfQT8t1BiGiSk949BbTOyPY47yC4lfkWmMmjvL19cKp6Liet1S_GIaV7zvPO7NHK1sk3EtBqXm0SO4pOg2oYFR9gOsmfWOC2_P0.Kdx3duCGTqiyRsC5hSkgaQ

it is a test card's encrypted data (5454545454545454 - 10 - 2019 - 123)

Then this request returns me same credit card and authorization. And I am saving this information.

Then I am trying to new authorization request with same card but different expiry dates (like: 5454545454545454 - 07 - 2022 - 123)

and it's encrypted data is different:

> eyJhbGciOiJSU0ExXzUiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwia2lkIjoiMSIsImNvbS53b3JsZHBheS5hcGlWZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4wIiwiY29tLndvcmxkcGF5LmxpYlZlcnNpb24iOiIxLjAuMSIsImNvbS53b3JsZHBheS5jaGFubmVsIjoiamF2YXNjcmlwdCJ9.gayFeZkSPGh9zYTEHj6qK9ikWNKDQ6kJApdEKlvfQqhsoK66PCwuFrIW50wbzBUQA_VGVSBFiOHF-iyHGVg1G7OQt3CIW0-bpvHN6dsVNzVKL5SXkL15oN8LpiH6W57Zk0IyWmhukMrsdeg_fqyHUW5AmkZ7sGMw7_FWMkyZsA07nFn90YvpXnS-ZIifr-cK3Kl4uoaitB6_mLKxh5l6ZlHa6eychbcjV-BHW8Hx0o9WHyl-MHrgZD2h8H9ulbWSkyQOMniV_--r-_ewN0znZaHdyv0BzzUoVHX4GliNmJpJ3iolkFeLl07H_i4rqdAOhBJprCm9eY3j8qgqOJNr4w.bh4c8SwzG8Lg2HTA.Gt0DCdG__Nc_eB8xAa8ziD7YNg5V8dOTcfOZUY4VG0Ta5hY7ekO57pDWcmmKD2BpEiZY34098zO8xC0PoR0gHb5k9G9dgkrLgFeC9ORfe7zZa_2tVe6vfJysZ7POkYqp8W2KMGaJEtZlGKDrLgPs26o.mcXSrq0ab-yOruwJNlpobQ

But Worldpay gives me same response.. (same masked credit card number and same dates with previous request.)

Are there any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learnt this issue come from Worldpay configuration for the development environment. So, don't spent time on this issue.